# Remove duplicates in a cell of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that has a lot of data for each cell. I want to remove the duplicates of each cell.

example:

```
([nan,"InversiÃ³n en CafÃ© 19 completada / InversiÃ³n en CafÃ© 19 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / login-device-verification-form / login-device-verification-form / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Players para Buyer Persona / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / login-device-verification-form / login-device-verification-form / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / login-device-verification-form / login-device-verification-form / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / login-device-verification-form / login-device-verification-form / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Players Junghanns - Planta Puebla / FOINBRA 2 - Players 13-07-2021 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / SG - Players 24-06-21 / Players Sports Garden 10 junio (pending y pagados) / Players Sports Garden 10 junio (pending y pagados) / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Clusters Foinbra R2 - C2 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Clusteres Before SG 2021.2 - C2--C3--C4 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Junghanns R2 - Players 18-03-2021 / Junghanns - Clusters - C2 - 1 / Junghanns R2 - Likes / Junghanns R1 - Players 03-03-2021 - 1 / Prueba MONEX - Players franquicias / Junghanns - Clusters - C2 / Junghanns R1 - Players 03-03-2021 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / ACIUM - Players 24-02-2021 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Players RegalÃ\xadas primer trimestre 2021 (con otras inversiones) / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / ACIUM - Inversionistas 9-02-2021 / ACIUM - Inversionistas 9-02-2021 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / McCarthy's R2 Players 26/ene/21 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / ACIUM - Players Promo Wallet / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma",
       'InversiÃ³n en CafÃ© 19 completada / InversiÃ³n en CafÃ© 19 / ingreso-a-webinar-cafe19 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Players Doopla - 18_10_2021 / La Vicenta - Likes / Players para Buyer Persona / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / SIN wallet | Players Diri | 20 agosto / Players Diri | Players SIN wallet / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Diri Compromisos 3 agosto 2021 / Players Compromiso de inversiÃ³n Diri (28/jul/21) / Players Galt 27/jul/21 / Players Junghanns - Planta Puebla / SG - Players 24-06-21 / Diri - Likes / Players Sports Garden 10 junio (pending y pagados) / Players Sports Garden 10 junio (pending y pagados) / Clusters Foinbra R2 - C2 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Clusteres Before SG 2021.2 - C2--C3--C4 / Junghanns - Clusters - C2 - 1 / Junghanns R1 - Players 03-03-2021 - 1 / Prueba MONEX - Players franquicias / Junghanns - Clusters - C2 / Junghanns R1 - Players 03-03-2021 / Players RegalÃ\xadas primer trimestre 2021 (con otras inversiones) / ACIUM - Inversionistas 9-02-2021 / ACIUM - Inversionistas 9-02-2021 / Doopla Players 9/2/21 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Galt Players 20/ene/21 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / ACIUM - Players Promo Wallet / CTLBdC - Segundo periodo de Pago / CTLBdC - Players primer cobro / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / FOINBRA - Cluster 2 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / CTLBdC - FOMO / Junghanns - Internal Recovery / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / CTLBdC - Cluster 1.1 / CTLBdC - Likes / PB - Players regalÃ\xadas/RBF / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Junghanns - Cluster 2.2 / Doopla - Visitantes al Snapshot / Doopla - Base 5 / Doopla - Base 3 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Cinnabon R2 23/07/2020 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Inversionistas Cinnabon 2 - Antes del 31 de Mayo / Cinnabon 2 - Promo external offering / Cinnabon 2 - FOMO 1 / Players Galt 05/05/2020 / PB - Players 29-04-2020 / Players Interactuando Ultimos 4 meses / La Borra Del Cafe Players 03.25.20 / Galt Energy - Inversionistas 24-03-2020 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / LBdC - Inversionistas 24_02_2020 / PB - Inversionistas 20_02_2020 (sin Galt) / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Inversionistas - 06_02_2020 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / Galt - Likes 30_01_2020 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / LBdC - Inversionistas 27_01_2020 / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma / interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma',
```

- `interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma` is several times in the string and I just want to have 1.

```
df_invertido['Eventos ultimos 100'] = df_invertido['Eventos ultimos 100'].str.split(r',\s+').map(set).str.join(", ")
```

I've tried this code.

Comment: Are you saying that all of `"InversiÃ³n en CafÃ© 19 completada / ....` is a single cell in your dataframe?

Comment: Yes. All the cells are similar

Comment: All the items that are potential duplicates, are they _always_ separated by slashes (`/`)?

Comment: Yes they are, always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using more or less the same strategy you were trying: *split, then set and join again*, I would try:

```
def clean_text(text):
    strings = text.split("/")
    strings = [item.strip() for item in strings]
    text = "/".join(set(strings))
    return text

df_invertido['Eventos ultimos 100'] = df_invertido['Eventos ultimos 100'].apply(clean_text)
```

The second line in the `clean_text` function accounts for items like  `/ interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma /` and `/ interacciÃ³n_con la plataforma/` that differ in trailing whitespaces.

Note that set does not necessarily conserve the order.

Comment: It still with some duplicates in each cell

Comment: There are items that are not perfect duplicates, but differ only in trailing whitespaces. I updated the code to deal with these cases.

Comment: It worked, I used it and it is fine thanks a lot.